# reactjs base class for all components

Tags: reactjs

I want to have a base component that all my higher order components extends it.  Something along the lines of

```
<BaseComponent>
   <App1>
      <... Other Components>
   </App1>
</BaseComponent>
```

where BaseComponent contains things such as

```
class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
        <Wrapper>
             {this.props.children}
             <ModalContainer>
             </ModalContainer>
        <Wrapper>);
    }
}
```

The ultimate goal is to be able to, in any of the Apps pass lets say "message = 'Error'" and a modal dialog will display saying "Error" without having to put the modal component in every single app.

Is this possible? or am I in the realm of unicorns.  I read a little about higher order compositions but at first glance, it doesn't seem like that's what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Component composition via higher-order components is a way to do something like subclassing but with composition instead of inheritance. For example:

```javascript
function wrapInBaseComponent(Component) {
  // Return a new component that renders `Component`
  // with all the same props, but also renders some
  // other stuff
  return (props) => {
    const { message, ...otherProps } = props;
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Component {...otherProps} />
        <ModalContainer message={message}>
        </ModalContainer>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  };
}
```

Then you'd do something like this:

```javascript
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

const WrappedComponent = wrapInBaseComponent(MyComponent);
```

Or, if you have ES7 decorators enabled, you can use it as a decorator:

```javascript
@wrapInBaseComponent
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // ...
}
```

This is how things like `react-redux` and `react-dnd` work; you don't inherit from `ReactReduxBaseComponent` or anything like that, you compose your component in a higher-order component that renders it, but adds additional functionality.

Comment: So if i wanted to render MyComponent, id do '<WrappedComponent>' ?

Comment: @LazyProgrammer In the first example, yes. Many people just export the wrapped version and don't even expose the non-wrapped one at all, but having access to it can be useful for testing.